# Iterate through all of the records in Realm right after a migration runs - Swift / iOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an iOS/Swift app where I need to change and add some new properties to a `Realm` object, which means I will have to create a new schema and change some of the existing data inside `Realm` accordingly so it works with the new changes.

Where would be the best place to place my code to restructure the existing data inside `Realm` as soon as the app launches?

**EDIT:**
I know how to create the migration and where to do it.

What I'm not sure is where would be a good place to iterate through all of the records in `Realm` right after the migration code runs to make some changes to the existing data in `Realm`.

To be more specific, the main reason I need to iterate though the records is because I'm currently using a `String` property to store `quantities` as follow... `2 pcs`, don't ask me why but now I need to remove `pcs` from the quantity values to leave just the `2` to be able to change the property to an `Int` or a `Double`. I know I know, that was silly to use a string to store quantities.

Comment: You may have already reviewed the docs but it seems you want to change the value of a property. That can be done in the migration block itself and is covered in the documentation [Updating Values](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-values). However, it seems you also want to change the property type. How you go about doing both really depends on the use case - do you need to maintain relationships? Do you have users working with the existing data?

Comment: I do have to maintain `one-to-many` relationships. I do have users with data and cannot be lost. My idea was to do the migration in the `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions` and then some where in my app, here is where I wasn't sure if `viewDidLoad` of the first view controller to be called in the app would be the best place to iterate through the data and make the necessary changes before the user requests the data. Thanks.

Comment: The migration block is really where all of those activities should occur. Changing data and/or properties around should happen before you app gets to that point because by that, your app is already talking to Realm and the objects have been established.

Comment: @Jay Can you please clarify something for me, in theory, can the `Realm` database be read from inside the `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions` method? I tried it but I keep getting error... `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` I also tried reading it from inside the migration block but I get the same error. Again, I think I will have to manually iterate through the data to be able to change the values for the `String` holding quantities to remove the suffix `pc` and `pcs` and leave just the quantity numbers.

Comment: Did you review the Updating Values link from my above comment? That's exactly what that code snippet does. In this case it takes the old objects firstName property value and the lastName property value and combines it into one string and stores it in the fullName property. I think that's what you are trying to do, right? Aren't you taking your string of *2 pc*, get the numeric part of that *2* and store it in another property?

Comment: @Jay - Yes, but the problem is that the `String` holding the value for the quantity contains both, the `2` and the `pc` as one single string and if I leave it as is, it will not work with a `Double` or an `Int`, I first need to separate the `2` from the `pc` but looping through the items and removing it. The `Updating Values` snippet would work if I had only the `2` stored in the string.  I know I know, storing the `pc` suffix as part of the quantity was not the smartest thing. I hope it make sense.

Comment: Well, this is a Swift question, not really a Realm question. In that migration you're going to have to parse the string into it's components, and then take the first component, covert to an int and store in a property. .componentsSeparated will do that pretty easily and the code could be in the migration block. What's the issue? I think you got this - just write the code.

Comment: Well, I know exactly how to do the separation, what I’m not sure is if doing this in the viewDidLoad of the first loaded storyboard would be the best place since doing it inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions generates the error I described in my previous comment. The question at this point is, if in theory I should be able to read Realm from inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: Hmm. The Realm example shows it being done in the migration block (which is where migrations are usually done) so why don't you do it there?

Comment: I didn’t work, it’s where I got the error.

Comment: Well, without including that code in the question, it would be hard to determine what the issue is. But, it appears you accepted an answer so you should be all set.

Comment: I think I now have everything figured out now. I'm doing my migrations in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as recommended and then in the `viewDidLoad` method of the first loaded storyboard, I'm going through the items and making the necessary data changes. Believe it or not, by having this debate I was able to make a better decision on how to approach my issue. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write migration code in AppDelegate's `disFinishLaunchWithOptions` method.

Please refer below references:

[realm.io official docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations)

**Local migrations:**

> Local migrations are defined by setting
>   Realm.Configuration.schemaVersion and
>   Realm.Configuration.migrationBlock. Your migration block provides all
>   the logic for converting data models from previous schemas to the new
>   schema. When creating a Realm with this configuration, the migration
>   block will be applied to update the Realm to the given schema version
>   if a migration is needed.
>
> Suppose we want to migrate the Person model declared earlier. The
>   minimal necessary migration block would be the following:

```
// Inside your application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

let config = Realm.Configuration(
    // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
    // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
    schemaVersion: 1,

    // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
    // a schema version lower than the one set above
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            // Nothing to do!
            // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
            // And will update the schema on disk automatically
        }
    })

// Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

// Now that we've told Realm how to handle the schema change, opening the file
// will automatically perform the migration
let realm = try! Realm()
```

**Update:**

[realm.io official docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) already all given information which is required for migration.

**Local migrations**

> If you want to add new property only then above code will work for
>   you. No need to iterate all records. The old record keeps its default
>   value with the respective row.

**Updating values**

> If you want to add a new property by using existing column value. You
>   need to iterate all the records. Please refer below code.

```
// Inside your application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            // The enumerateObjects(ofType:_:) method iterates
            // over every Person object stored in the Realm file
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Person.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                // combine name fields into a single field
                let firstName = oldObject!["firstName"] as! String
                let lastName = oldObject!["lastName"] as! String
                newObject!["fullName"] = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
            }
        }
    })
```

**Renaming properties**

> If you just want to rename property only then use below code.

```
// Inside your application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                // The renaming operation should be done outside of calls to `enumerateObjects(ofType: _:)`.
                migration.renameProperty(onType: Person.className(), from: "yearsSinceBirth", to: "age")
            }
        })
```

Comment: @ iMHitesh Surani - I know how and where to put the migration code, what I'm not sure and probably I wasn't clear about it is that I need to iterate through all of the records in `Realm` after the migrations runs to make some tweaks to the existing data. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: @ iMHitesh Surani - I'm going to accept your edited answer since it has really good information about migrations. FYI - The main reason I need to iterate though the records is because I'm currently using a `String` property to store an `item quantity` as follow... `2 pcs`, don't ask me why but now I need to remove `pcs` from the quantity values to leave just the `2` to be able to change the property to an `Int` or a `Double`. I know I know, that was silly to use a string to store quantities.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  I know I know, that was silly to use a string to store quantities: It silly things but you are doing changes that are good.